# Find $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan 11x}{\tan 13x}$. How to choose an interval for this function s.t we can use L'Hospital's rule.

Tags: calculus, limits

Find
$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan 11x}{\tan 13x}$$

Using L'Hospital by brute force we get $13/11$. However we can only use the rule when both functions $\tan 11x$ and $\tan 13x$ are defined on a common interval $I$ with a further condition that for each $x \in I$, $\tan 13x \neq 0$. How should I choose this interval or redefine the functions  in order to guarantee that the conditions for using L'Hospital's rule are satisfied? Is there a better approach to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let $x-\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } =t$

$$\lim _{ x\to \frac { \pi  }{ 2 }  } \frac { \tan  11x }{ \tan  13x } =\lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 } \frac { \tan  11\left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } +t \right)  }{ \tan  13\left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } +t \right)  } =\\ =\lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 } \frac { \tan  \left( \frac { 11\pi  }{ 2 } +11t \right)  }{ \tan  \left( \frac { 13\pi  }{ 2 } +13t \right)  } =\lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 } \frac { \tan  \left( \frac { 3\pi  }{ 2 } +11t \right)  }{ \tan  \left( \frac { \pi  }{ 2 } +13t \right)  } =\\ =\lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 } \frac { -\cot { \left( 11t \right)  }  }{ -\cot { \left( 13t \right)  }  } =\lim _{ t\rightarrow 0 } \frac { \tan { \left( 13t \right)  }  }{ 13t } \frac { 11t }{ \tan { \left( 11t \right)  }  } \frac { 13 }{ 11 } =\frac { 13 }{ 11 } \\ $$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Set $\;x=\frac\pi2-t$, $t\to 0$, and use the elementary properties of trigonometric functions:
$$\tan 11x=\tan\Bigl(\frac{11\pi}2-11t\Bigr)=\tan\Bigl(5\pi+\frac{\pi}2-11t\Bigr)=\tan\Bigl(\frac{\pi}2-11t\Bigr)=\frac 1{\tan 11t}.$$
Similarly, $\;\tan 13x=\dfrac 1{\tan 13t}$, so that, using equivalence near $t=0$, we have
$$\frac{\tan 11x}{\tan 13x}=\frac{\tan 13t}{\tan 11t}\sim_0\frac{13t}{11t}=\frac{13}{11}.$$